# ¿Cómo Comentar y Descomentar rapidamente un código?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

En ocasiones tengo la necesidad de probar:
    Un ejemplo de código o una variante del mismo.
    Esto es necesario para probar una nueva funcionalidad o
    para testear su implementación o rendimiento.
    El código puede ser muy largo.
Así que necesito alguna forma de poder comentar rápidamente el código con

```
/*  
 * mi código  
 * …  
 * /
```

O con:

```
//  
// mi código  
// …  
//
```

Cuando el código es muy largo, es engorroso hacer:
  Selecciona todo el código que no quieres ejecutar y coméntalo,
  Escribe o inserta el código que quieres probar,
  Haz pruebas o lo que sea …
Ahora …
  Selecciona y comenta el nuevo bloque de código.
  Busca y selecciona el código anterior, y descoméntalo.
  Haz pruebas o lo que sea …
Y así necesito hacerlo muchas veces ya que me estoy reciclando,
  pues hace como treinta años que no programo casi nada.

¿Hay alguna forma o truco para hacerlo rápidamente?

Comment: esto no es un pregunta, más bien una respuesta. Es buen dato pero deberias modificarla para que se ajuste al formato de stack overflow

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que preguntas, tienes algun error, inconveniente o problema. Asi tal cual como esta no cumple el estandar del sitio.

Comment: ¡Lo siento! 
No se como hacerlo.

Comment: Talvez podrias realizar la pregunta y responderla para que la colaboracion sea mas clara.

Comment: ¿Lo pueden hacer por mí?

Comment: En Visual Studio. Selecciona toda la fracción del código que quieres comentar Presiona CTRL + K + C (Una tecla a la vez). Para descomentar código de igual forma selecciona el código que quieres descomentar y presiona CTRL + K + D

Comment: Mi recomendación edita tu pregunta y redacta lo que necesitas lograr y que no sabías cómo, muestra algo que hayas intentado y debajo en la zona de respuestas publica cómo lograr lo que preguntas; no solo le daría más orden a tu publicación, sería muy útil a la comunidad y recibirías votos a favor

Comment: Hice los cambios sugeridos y espero haberlo hecho bien ;)

Comment: Aviso a todos: (Tan solo en poco más de dos meses) [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/513945/comment-and-uncomment-blocks-of-code-quickly.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/513945/comment-and-uncomment-blocks-of-code-quickly.html) Jane Wu [MSFT] 03 de Abr en 10:16 Gracias por tomarse el tiempo para dar su sugerencia. Vamos a hacer algunas comprobaciones preliminares para asegurarse de que nosotros podemos seguir adelante. Proporcionaremos una actualización una vez que la cuestión ha sido clasificada por el equipo de producto. 0 Dante Gagne [MS

Answer (score 6):

Considera instalar y usar Visual Studio Code como IDE si quieres tener ese tipo de shortcuts. Por ejemplo, tienes estos dos de origen para el propósito que mencionas:

`Ctrl + K + C` - Comenta todo el código seleccionado.

`Ctrl + K + U` - Descomenta todo el código seleccionado.

Comment: Eso también funciona, pero tienes que localizar el código, seleccionarlo comentarlo o descomentarlo, y así sucesivamente. De este modo lo tienes fácilmente localizado y con añadir o quitar tan solo un "/" ya lo haces.

Comment: Esos shortcuts son de Visual Studio, creo que no aplican para Visual Studio Code

Comment: Hola, si que aplican, los uso diariamente en VSC

Answer (score 3):

**Truco:**
Cuando tenemos un código muy largo y necesitamos comentar y descomentar rápidamente:
Agregue al principio del bloque:
`/* //TODO: Comentar  o Descomentar este bloque.
   //Quite una barra inclinada al principio de la línea para descomentar.
   //Añada una barra inclinada al principio de la línea para comentar.`
Y agregue al final del bloque
`/*/`
La etiqueta TODO: te muestra en tareas el mensaje, 
para poder localizarlo rápidamente.
Además el código comentado se puede colapsar en el [+] cuando está comentado.

Código comentado:

```
[+] /*//TODO: Añadir una "/"  al inicio para Descomentar.
      //Este bloque hace algo.
       ...
       Código 100000,0 líneas.
       ...
   /*/
```

Código sin comentar:

```
   //* //TODO: Quitar una "/" al inicio para comentar.
      //Este bloque hace algo.
[+]    ...
       Código 100000,0 líneas.
       ...
/*/
```

No sabía como decirle a todo el mundo, como lo hago yo.
Espero que les sea útil.

Comment: @Jorjesys Se que este comentario será borrado.  ¡Den las gracias a quien reformateó mi pregunta y respuesta! Solo una aclaración. En Java, por ejemplo, el comentario dentro del `//*/` final no funciona, pero en el `/*comentario/` intermedio para alternar, si lo permite. No tengo suficiente experiencia en otros lenguajes, pero creo funciona en VS code VS community, en todos los que admiten comentarios de este tipo. Hice un pequeño manual en [Switch-lines-code-C-Sharp-VS](https://github.com/ManuelRCastroIglesias/Switch-lines-code_C-Sharp-VS).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día:
Ya está implementado en Visual Studio 
Para  comentar y descomentar código de una manera rápida y sencilla.
La he probado en CSharp (es donde la aplicaba originalmente)
Consiste en lo siguiente:
1.- Añada en donde quiere que se inicie el código comentado:

```
//*TODO:1_INI Quita una barra del principio para marcar como comentario hasta TODO:1_END/
Código a comentar/descomentar
….
Código a comentar/descomentar
```

Añada al final del código a comentar/descomentar:

```
/*TODO:1_END*/
```

Funcionamiento:
Para comentar quite del inicio de comentario una de las barra del principio y automáticamente se comentará todo el código.
Para descomentar añada la barra que quitó,
al incluir las etiquetas

```
TODO:(algo)_INI
 … 
TODO:(algo)_FIN
```

,
Aparecen en la lista de tareas con lo que es fácil ir a esas partes sin tener que recorrer todo el código, y después con solo borrar o añadir la barra / el proceso es rapidísimo.
[image: Código comentado]
[image: Código comentado]
Espero les  sea de utilidad.
¡Gracias!